# Pass array containing float singletons and arrays into a njit function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

Consider the following function:

```py
from numba import njit
import numpy as np


def get_rate(arr: np.ndarray) -> float:

    v = 1
    for i in arr:
        if isinstance(i, float):
            v *= (1 - i / 100)
        else:
            j = np.random.randint(0, len(i))
            v *= (1 - i[j] / 100)

    return v
```

The function iterates over an array and applies an exact or random quote from a collection cumulatively.

Unfortunately, I have the following input array:

```py
a = np.array([1.0, np.array([2.0, 0.0, 2.0, 3.0]), 3.0, 2.0, 4.0, 10.0, np.array([4.0, 3.0, 1.5, 2.0])])
```

You can assume that each entry is either a float or an array with length four. The function works fine as it is. However, as my whole code infrastructure is build upon njit, I have to rely on `numba's` just-in-time compiler `njit` for this function as well. But I do not know whether `njit` can handle arrays that contain float singletons and array data types. It would also be fine to convert the input array to a Dict.

```py
from numba.typed import Dict

d = Dict.empty(key_type=np.int64, value_type=...)
```

My solution so far:

I convert the array to a matrix, where I zip each row according to the longest row. Then, I can just use the function `get_rate` decorated by `njit`.

Matrix conversion:

```py
ls = list(map(lambda v: list(v) if isinstance(v, np.ndarray) else [v], list(a)))
a = np.array(list(zip_longest(*ls, fillvalue=np.nan))).T
a = pd.DataFrame(a).fillna(method="ffill", axis=1).values
```

Can I somehow specify the `dtype` argument to make `numba` accept such arrays with different data types? Is there a pure numba approach to get the same result?

Comment: You can use generated jit and call to specialized functions for arrays or floats inside that function. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/generated-jit.html

Comment: The problem is the input itself which does not have a well defined native type and cannot have one. You need to change the input if you want a jitted function (or any efficient compiled function) to work on it. If you cannot, then the only solution is to use Numba on each item and not in the function iterating on the whole array (actually Numba can be used in object mode but it will be nearly useless).

Comment: A Numpy array is not meant to contain objects though it support this (not efficiently). In this case, you can just use lists. You can also convert scalars to array if it make sense in your computation. A list of 1D arrays containing only floats has a well-defined type. An alternative solution is to use one big array and provide another array to the Numba function describing the slice/location of the sub-array in the big array, and possibly another array to describe if the slice should be considered as a scalar or an array if needed.

Comment: But different handling of arrays with shpae[0]==1 would directly solve the problem?

Comment: @max9111 thanks for that hint, much appreciated! Unfortunately, just using generated jit instead of njit doesn't work. Also, I am not quite sure if njit can just be replaced by generated jit without any code modification, and changing the infrastructure whould just take way to long :/

Comment: @JérômeRichard, thanks for your comment as well. Yeah well, I will try to implement you suggestion. Otherwise, I would just change the input array

Comment: Maybe awkward-array is of interest, I've never used it but it seems to have some Numba interoperability. 
https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward